# In a mysql transaction, can $pdo handle be used for multiple queries or just once?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions, prepare

I want to begin a transaction with multiple queries in MySQL and through self-learning, I write my code like:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project', '', '', array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
));

$pdo->beginTransaction();

try {

    // First Query

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = 1";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        // There should be only one row so I used if
    }
    else {
    }

    // Second Query

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = 1";
    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->execute();
    if ($row = $stmt2->fetch()) {
    }
    else {
    }
    $pdo->commit();
    echo "OK!";
}

catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $pdo->rollBack();
}
```

So in my code I used the same $pdo twice like

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
```

and then

```
$pdo->commit();
```

When it is just one stmt the code will show the database data fine.

I haven't successfully tested it since there are syntax errors in other files that prevent this from running. I'm very new to PDO, so could anyone tell me if this is fine to run? Thanks!

Comment: Did anything in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) suggest otherwise?

Comment: Thanks! I just roughly checked the manual and I don't think so... The example seems most of the times use only 1 query?

Comment: This looks fine. If you're not getting any errors and you can't break it, I think you're on the right track. When using transactions it's *important* to use the same connection. They are not shared between different connections, after all.

Comment: Thanks! I will try fixing the syntax errors and see if this can be executed and get back to you :)D

Comment: @tadman I've fixed syntax errors and the code runs with no flaws and the data is successfully updated in the db as well! :D

Comment: Are your tables `InnoDB` or `MyISAM` ?  My question has relevance regarding `$pdo->commit()` and `$pdo->rollBack();`.

Comment: First of all, using a transaction for a select query makes no sense.

Comment: Hi @YourCommonSense, thanks for your comment. I am very new to transaction and PDO. The reason I perform select query in a transaction is because I want to prevent the customer from getting wrong database information if there is another user is updating the database when you perform the select query, so my initial thinking is that the result should only be displayed after the user has updated the database, let's say for an inventory information. I might be wrong to code like this but this is my intention. Could you correct me if my code would not make this happen? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. if there is another user is updating the database, do you want the first user to get the value before update or after? What's wrong in either case?

Comment: I want the first user to get the value after the update. Say if A is browsing an amazon product page and now B enters, I want B to wait until A finished browsing to see this page since A might have purchased some certain number of this products so A has updated the inventory info in this db. I think I know my problem now. Would it make since if I perform an UPDATE query after SELECT??

Comment: Yes, it would. However, to make 100% sure you have to perform a LOCK which is what you really want, not a transaction. But for the time being I wouldn't care of such issues too much. It will take too long a time for your shop to reach a state when such a race condition could occur

Comment: Yea you are right I didn't think about UPDATE at first, only the SELECT wouldn't make any sense. Thanks for solving my problem! You actually have answered my real question haha. Ok I will take time to learn LOCK later 

Answer (score 0):

Example (PDO) using '?'

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(175, 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

Looking to the example you can see your mistakes.

first:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = ?";
```

second:

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    for($id=1;$id<3;$id++){
        $stmt->execute($id);
        $result=$stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

Sorry for my English but it's not my mother tongue.

Comment: Thanks Jose! Not a problem English is not my mother language neither... I am Chinese. I have a great friend from Columbia named Jose as well! Yes I am aware of the ? thing but since I am very new to it I just want to keep it simple. However the code runs successfully without any binding '?' in it, but I will definitely look into that once I begin to learn PDO thoroughly. Thanks again Jose I am looking at your code now :)

Comment: You have several ways to do the querys. If you want to learn a little more, I'll give you 2 websites that can help you:                                                      http://php.net     and   https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Yo why not! What's your suggested website??

Comment: You should answer the question asked, not just rant on some unrelated topic.